# Clever Objects, and Procedural to OOP mindset transition

Tags: ruby, oop

In POODR, author Sandi Metz gives an example a Trip class, that needs to be prepared.
The Trip class defines a method `prepare`, which from the outside appears to say it can prepare it self,
but in fact it does so by internally asking some other object to prepare it, like bellow

```
class Trip
  def initialize(preparers)
    @preparers = preparers || []
  end

  def prepare
    @preparers.each do |preparer|
      preparer.prepare(self)
    end
  end
end
```

Given we never know of an object's internals, looking only from the outside this
seems a bit odd as it makes the object appear to be clever. I mean how can a trip
know how to prepare it self.

However, if we don't do this we go back to just having data structures
whose state is controlled by some outside function.

Thinking more of it, IRL I usually tell my baby brother "cut your hair", but in fact,
what happens is he goes to the barber shop, and has them cut his hair.
So the notion is not that weird and might apply to objects.

I can't put a name to this yet, but it makes me think I've been misunderstanding
messages for what an object can do, when in fact they're just what an object
can accept and respond to. We never know an object's internals so who
cares about how it goes about responding to messages.

- Is this line of thinking correct?
- Is this what it means by intent and implementation separation?
- Or the analogy doesn't fall it line at all.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I send you a letter saying "please, compute 2+2 for me", and I get a letter back which says "4", I have no idea how you come up with that answer, you may have memorized it, you may have looked it up, you may have computed it by hand, you may have used a calculator, you may have sent a letter to someone else asking them to compute 2+2, you may have sent several letters to several other people asking them to compute sub-problems of 2+2, you may have read the letter and decided based on its contents to pass it on to a specialist, you may have *not* read the letter and just blindly passed it on to someone else without even opening it, or your secretary may have opened it and answered on your behalf without you even knowing about it.

That's the fundamental nature of messaging: I cannot, should not, and *must not* know how you were able to answer. The *only* thing I can observe is the answer. As long as the answer is correct, it doesn't matter to me how the answer was obtained. Maybe it was printed out, mailed to China, computed by hand in an office, then mailed back and scanned. I don't know and I don't care.

> - Is this line of thinking correct?

Yes.

> - Is this what it means by intent and implementation separation?

I am not familiar with that phrase. Is that something from the book? If yes, you should explain what it means in your question.

> - Or the analogy doesn't fall it line at all.

No, the messaging metaphor is a good one. It is the *fundamental* idea of OO. Classes are irrelevant, even objects are irrelevant. [Messaging is what it's all about](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/squeak-dev/1998-October/017019.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is the lack of context / domain. If this `Trip` is used, for example, by the hotel / resort, then this is a mistake. If `Trip` exists in the minds of travelers, then this is a good design. For people, a trip is, in particular, a list of people traveling with them and the opportunity to notify them of the preparation for the trip.

I would solve this problem by more expressive naming of classes, modules / packages, etc.